# Back button navigation isn't working when there are multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, back

There are 3 fragments firstTabFragment, secondTabFragemnt and thirdTabFragment in my code. I'm calling those fragments in another fragment like this:

```
private FirstTabFragment firstTabFragment;
private ThirdTabFragment thirdTabFragment;
private SecondTabFragment secondTabFragment;
```

I'm using setter methods as given below:

```
// setter method for fragments
public void setFirstTabInstance(FirstTabFragment firstTabFragment){
    this.firstTabFragment = firstTabFragment;
}

public void setThirdTabInstance(ThirdTabFragment thirdTabFragment){
    this.thirdTabFragment = thirdTabFragment;
}

public void setSecondTabInstance(SecondTabFragment secondTabFragment){
    this.secondTabFragment = secondTabFragment;
}
```

Now I want to add back button navigation behavior, here is the code for that:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {

        case R.id.viewProfileBack:

            if(firstTabFragment!= null)
                firstTabFragment.popBackStack();
            else if(thirdTabFragment != null)
                thirdTabFragment.popBackStack();             

            Log.e(TAG, "Going back to " + firstTabFragment);
            Log.e(TAG, "Going back to " + thirdTabFragment);
            break;
}  
}
```

in `firstTabFragment`, `popBackStack` method is as given below:

```
public void popBackStack() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();

        int backStackEntryCount = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        System.out.println(backStackEntryCount);

        if (backStackEntryCount > 0) {
            @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi") Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.getFragments().get(backStackEntryCount - 2);
            if (fragment instanceof PeopleProfileFragment) {
                ((PeopleProfileFragment) fragment).refresh();
            } else if (fragment instanceof OrgStructureFragment) {
                ((OrgStructureFragment) fragment).refresh();

            } else if (fragment instanceof SearchDashboardFragment) {
                ((SearchDashboardFragment) fragment).animateBack();
                ((SearchDashboardFragment) fragment).refreshView();
            } else if (fragment instanceof AddToCircleFragment) {

                ((AddToCircleFragment) fragment).refresh();

                if(recentCircleId!= null)
                    ((AddToCircleFragment) fragment).setRecentCircleId(recentCircleId);
           }
            navigateBack();
        }
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
    }
```

in `thirdTabFragment`, `popBackStack` method is as given below:

```
public void popBackStack() {
    backStack();
}
```

When `viewProfileBack` is clicked, it should either go to methods defined in `firstTabFragment` or `thirdTabFragment`. However both `firstTabFragment` and `thirdTabFragment` are null. I'm not understanding why they are null. Would appreciate help here.

Answer (score 2):

Your backstack is Null. I think you are not adding fragment into backstack.
While clicking on fragment **add that fragment to backstack** using this

```
Newfragment firstFragment = new Newfragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.article_fragment, firstFragment)
.addToBackStack(null).commit();
```